# Sort Array value based on another array value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array selections:

```
var selections = ( JSON.stringify($('#approval').select2('data')) );
var selections =  JSON.parse("[" + selections + "]");
```

console.log from selections is:
[image]

I want to sort it base on approvalValue array, here is the array:

[image]

I've try this, but not working, nothing changed:

```
var i = 0;
selections.sort(function(a,b){
  return approvalValue.indexOf(a[0][i]['element']['id']) < approvalValue.indexOf(b[0][i]['element']['id']) ? -1 : 1;
 i = i+1;
});
```

How to sort selections with id 151,149 then 150?

Answer (score 0):

Try plucking the id out of second array, something like (using a map or something else):

```
var sorting = [ 151, 149, 150];
```

Then iterate through the first array and sort it based on that:

```
var result = []

sorting.forEach(function(key) {
var found = false;
selections = selections.filter(function(item) {
    if(!found && item[1] == key) {
        result.push(item);
        found = true;
        return false;
    } else 
        return true;
    })
})
```